# Ошибка при создании интерфейса: "Unable to parse template "Interface" Idea"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Использую Intellij IDEA. 
При создании интерфейса IDE выдает ошибку:

> Unable to parse template "Interface"
>   Error message: This template did not produce a Java class or an interface

Как пофиксить это?

Comment: У вас просто проект? Может у вас подключен Gradle или Maven? Какая у вас версия идеи? И попробуйте перезапустить.

Comment: @AntonSorokin обычный javaee проект. ничего не подключено. idea - 2016,3. перезапускал.

Comment: Так переустановите, желательно обновленную версию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Похожая проблема встречается у многих людей, но не с интерфейсами, а с классами.

Вот несколько решений:

1)Попробуйте перезапустить или обновить Идею.

2)Попробуйте перезапустить Идею используя <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> → Invalidate Caches / Restart

3)Попробуйте создать класс, а потом в java файле напишите не `class`, а `interface`.

4) Решения проблем с классами. Возможно, вам что-то поможет:

> Перейдите в меню File → Settings → Editor → 
>   File and code templates,
>   выберите «Interface» на вкладке «Files» и напишите
>
> ```
>  #if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end #parse("File Header.java") public interface ${NAME} {}
> ```

Или

> Добавьте следующую строку в свой пользовательский параметр виртуальной
>   машины (studio.vmoptions).
>
> `-Djdk.util.zip.ensureTrailingSlash=false`

(Источники: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45497266/unable-to-parse-template-class), [2](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206922365-Unable-to-parse-template-Class-Error-message-This-template-did-not-produce-a-Java-class-or-an-interface-during-New-Java-Class), [3](https://www.reddit.com/r/AndroidStudio/comments/6rzgz3/unable_to_parse_template_class_error_message_this/))

В крайнем случае вы можете переустановить IntelliJ IDEA(все ваши проекты сохранятся). Если просто переустановка не поможет, сделайте полную переустановку. Т.е. удалите идею, удалите остаточные файлы, удалите настройки, можете почистить реестр. А потом выполните установку.

Comment: Ваши источники применимы только к классам, а я не могу создать интерфейс

Comment: @Vlad Я знаю, я же сам это написал. " Решения проблем с классами. Возможно, вам что-то поможет"

Comment: @Vlad обновил ответ, посмотрите способ 3)

Comment: можно ещё просто файл создать с расширение java и там тоже написать интерфейс)

Comment: я разобрался, подправьте ваш пункт №4 в конце вместо class - interface надо поставить